# Pagination and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, inner-join

I have a situation which I need to do pagination along with `INNET JOIN`. Here is a similar scenario I have:

```
DECLARE @categories AS TABLE(
    CatID INT,
    CategoryName NVARCHAR(100)
);

DECLARE @fooTable AS TABLE(
    ID INT,
    CatID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(100),
    MinAllow INT,
    Price DECIMAL(18,2)
);

INSERT INTO @categories  VALUES(1, 'Cat1');
INSERT INTO @categories  VALUES(2, 'Cat2');
INSERT INTO @categories  VALUES(3, 'Cat3');
INSERT INTO @categories  VALUES(4, 'Cat4');
INSERT INTO @categories  VALUES(5, 'Cat5');

INSERT INTO @fooTable  VALUES(1, 1, 'Product1', 2, 112.2);
INSERT INTO @fooTable  VALUES(3, 1, 'Product3', 5, 233.32);
INSERT INTO @fooTable  VALUES(6, 1, 'Product6', 4, 12.43);
INSERT INTO @fooTable  VALUES(7, 4, 'Product7', 4, 12.43);
INSERT INTO @fooTable  VALUES(8, 5, 'Product8', 4, 12.43);
```

These are the records I have. As you can see, some categories do not have any products inside `@fooTable`. As a next step, we have the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM @fooTable ft
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CatID) AS RowNum, * FROM @categories
) AS cat ON (cat.CatID = ft.CatID);
```

It is a basic JOIN except that the output will also carry the row number of the categories. The result I got for this query is as follows:

```
ID   CatID   Name          MinAllow    Price     RowNum   CatID    CategoryName
---- ------- ------------- ----------- --------- -------- -------- -------------
1    1       Product1      2           112.20    1        1        Cat1
3    1       Product3      5           233.32    1        1        Cat1
6    1       Product6      4           12.43     1        1        Cat1
7    4       Product7      4           12.43     4        4        Cat4
8    5       Product8      4           12.43     5        5        Cat5
```

When you look at the `RowNum` column, you will see that those values are not pagination friendly. So, when I try to paginate this table as follows, I got an incorrect output:

```
SELECT * FROM @fooTable ft
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CatID) AS RowNum, * FROM @categories
)AS cat ON (cat.CatID = ft.CatID) AND (cat.RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 2);
```

The real situation I have is similar to this one but that query is so complicated and I need to get it working with INNER JOIN. I hope I made it clear. Any idea how I got something like that working?

**Edit**

According to the above result of my first select query, I should be able to retrieve products whose `CatID` is 1 and 4 on my second query. That's what I aim.

Comment: You should use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...)` in the first `SELECT` and not in derived table `INNER JOIN (SELECT ...) as cat`.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean thanks but that does not solve my main problem. I want to paginate Categories not products. And based on that, I should retrieve the proper products. What I mean by that is that I should be able to get the products whose CatID is 1 and 4 in my above case.

Comment: See my answer. You could use [`DENSE_RANK` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution can be the next one:

```
SELECT  x.*
FROM
(
        SELECT  ft.*, 
                cat.CategoryName,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ft.CatID) AS Rnk
        FROM @fooTable ft
        INNER JOIN @categories cat ON (cat.CatID = ft.CatID)
) AS x
WHERE   x.Rnk BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Results:

```
ID CatID Name     MinAllow Price   CategoryName Rnk
-- ----- -------- -------- ------- ------------ ---
1  1     Product1 2        112.20  Cat1         1
3  1     Product3 5        233.32  Cat1         1
6  1     Product6 4        12.43   Cat1         1
7  4     Product7 4        12.43   Cat4         2
```